# How to know and then prompt user that the source table of SSRS is currently updating?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

So basically, I have a tablix where available values is based on a stored procedure. I have a stored procedure (**usp_SSIS_DailySales**) that populates 
my Datamart table (this is where the aggregation and pre-computation happens)  (**Data_DailySales**) ***daily every 3hrs*** then I have another stored procedure (**usp_SSRS_DailySales**) that only selects the data from Data_DailySales.

What I want to do is during run-time, the report will prompt the user if the Data_DailySales table is currently being populated so they need to generate the report after 3hrs. And also prompt the user if the retrieved data is nothing, I already solved this one using *NoRowsMessage*...I just need to solve the above mention problem...

any suggestion and help is appreciated!
thanks a bunch!

Comment: hows the `usp_SSIS_DailySales` and `usp_SSRS_DailySales` scheduled?

Comment: usp_SSIS_DailySales is scheduled every 3hrs daily...usp_SSRS_DailySales is not scheduled because it only selects data from Data_DailySales to be used as dataset in SSRS

Comment: Sorry about `usp_SSRS_DailySales`. how is the `usp_SSIS_DailySales` scheduled, through SQL Server Agent Job?

Comment: That is correct..the usp_SSIS_DailySales scheduled through SQL Server Agent Job

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to usp_SSRS_DailySales to return the current state of the update progress. It would have the same value on every row, e.g. 'Currently Updating'.

You could show that value in a textbox, or you could set the visibility of a textbox or any other design object, e.g.

`= First ( Fields!Update_Status.Value, "usp_SSRS_DailySales" ) = "Currently Updating"`

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives you the currently executing jobs :-

```
SELECT
    ja.job_id,
    j.name AS job_name,
    ja.start_execution_date,      
    ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS current_executed_step_id,
    Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh 
    ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC)
AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

You can use this as a dataset to find out if `usp_SSIS_DailySales` job is running or not. If yes, show a message like you did for *NoRowsMessage*, if no, show the data tablix.